# Repetitive patterns in テープレコーダーを使った放送に加えて、駅員が同じことを言ったりして、同じことを3回ぐらいアナウンスする

Tags: grammar

> テープレコーダーを使った放送に**加えて**、駅員が同じことを言ったりして、同じことを3回ぐらいアナウンスする。([source line 21-22](https://www.docdroid.net/XIK9pCk/img-20171020-0001-new.pdf))

My attempt at translation:

> Adding up in a broadcast using a prerecorded tape, the station attendant says the same thing and announces the same thing 3 times.

First, I decided for 加えて to be the て-form of the verb instead of the conjunction because I couldn't make any sense of this first part テープレコーダーを使った放送に**加えて** without a verbal expression. I might've overlooked something, but I just couldn't find a solution for this approach.

Second, the way I translated and integrated テープレコーダーを使った放送に**加えて** seems kind of wrong. The following *駅員が同じことを言ったりして、*  **同じことを3回ぐらいアナウンスする** already repeats that the same information is given (italic part) and is given multiple times (bold part). This in itself feels redundant.
Then, in addition, I give the information that this information is "adding up" (stacked?) in a prerecorded tape.

If I translated the part 駅員が同じことを言ったりして、同じことを3回ぐらいアナウンスする。 a bit more creatively, I could make it into something like:

> The station attendant says the same thing and the same 3 times over.

The repetition of "the same thing" in the full sentence could be interpreted as a way to mimic the repetitive character of these announcements. However, if that should be the case, I'm having a very hard time to put enough trust into this interpretation of mine since it renders a good portion of the full sentence "redundant, repetitive" information.

(Note: I left out the additional アナウンスする on purpose in this second translation, since the intent of this translation was to show what I deem to be the essence of this construction of repetitive expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

加{くわ}えて is the て-form of 加{くわ}える, but it works as a conjunction.

xに加{くわ}えてyもする literally means "Adding to (doing) x, we also do y", or more naturally in English, "in addition to x, we also do y"

As for the second part of your questions, I interpret the second 同{おな}じ to refer to the announcement in general whereas the first 同{おな}じ means that the station attendant says the same thing as the tape recorder. There are two reasons for this,

1. The part directly following the conjunctive verb belongs to the part directly before it (i.e., the clause 駅員が同じことを言ったりして is connected to テープレコーダーを使った放送)
2. The first part is still lacking an action, which is given by the last part (アナウンスする)

   My full translation would thus be:

   In addition to using a tape recorder, 
   the station attendant also repeats the message, 
   such that the announcement is done three times.